# Monitor/sniff PCI I/O under Windows and Linux

Tags: linux-kernel, pci, sniffing, pci-bus, windows-driver

A PCI device seems to have some sort of incompatibility with the process of I/O port range assignment on Linux, even if it works on Windows without any effort with a completely blank driver.

I would like to compare the I/O port range assignment process on Windows and Linux.

For that I need to monitor reads/writes to PCI I/O ports and memory. Primarily, I/O ports.

Unfortunately I don't own a hardware PCI sniffer, or anything that is capable of monitoring all PCI I/O lines at 33MHz.

Is there any way to monitor I/O in software for Windows and/or Linux?

Comment: At Linux you may see the PCI configuration space before OS does anything to it by adding `pci=earlydump` into the kernel command line (from bootloader). On Windows there are definitely tools that allow to see what's going on on the I/O bus, but I'm not a Windows guy.

Comment: Thanks! I will try that. But sadly it doesn't really answer my question - I understand what the device tells Linux to do, I'd like to see what Linux actually does. It is possible to derive it from meticulously studying the source code, but I would appreciate an easier way.